# Cordova android mapped to which android API

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-android

When using Cordova I want to build for Android API version 23.

When I do `cordova platform add android` then when I build the app by doing `cordova build android`. It builds for API 25 by default.

How do I go about setting the correct api version. Also mention what is to be installed in the Android-sdk.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Android API version 6? Android APi 6 is Android 2.0.1. Do you mean Android 6.0, which is Android API 23?

Comment: yes my bad I mean android v 6 API 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about setting the correct api version

In your `config.xml`, use a [`<preference>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#preference) to set it:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

> Also mention what is to be installed in the Android-sdk

The API 23 platform SDK needs to be installed.
See the [Cordova Android platform guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#installing-the-requirements) for more details.

Comment: is there a way to check the api version of an built apk file?